# Calling Powershell commands remotely through psexec

Tags: powershell, remote-server, psexec

I'm trying to execute Get-ChildItem (to find latest dot net version)on remote server using psexec but it gets executed on local system: 
Below is my code:

```
$server = "x.x.x.x"
Invoke-Expression ".\psexec \\$($server) powershell (Get-ChildItem -Path 
$Env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework |Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1).Name"
```

Output:

```
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
The term v4.0.30319 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:11
+ v4.0.30319 <<<<
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (v4.0.30319:String) [], CommandN
otFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This means script is able to run and find v4.0.30319 version but on the local system.
How can I get it to run on the intended server without any error and without getting haulted abruptly? (Right now script executes and haults without exiting)

**Note 1.** I've tried to make use of other connections methods as well like `PSSession`, `Invoke-Command` scriptblock method but all throw :

```
WinRM not started
```

**Note 2.** I'm using psexec since `Get-ChildItem` doesnt has `-computername`. And secondly, I'm successfully able to to use psexec with below command:

```
Invoke-Expression ".\PsExec.exe \\$($server) route add 10.38.5.0 mask 255.255.254.0 $($gate) -p"
```

**Note 3.** I've tested the connection with the server through psexec seprately with below command: `\psexec.exe \\10.150.19.108 hostname`

and it returns the name of that server, which proves psexec connection is established.

Just want to know , how to make powershell commands run through psexec? The solution will reduce half of the effort in my project if someone could help!

Comment: One approach that may be easier is to "Enable-PSRemoting" with PSExec, run your script, then loop back at the end and disabling PSRemoting if that's what your environment requires.  The "WinRM not started" error would be resolved this way.  Would this be an acceptable solution?

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is bad because it exposes your script to injection.  I'd suggest using `&` instead.  Try explicitly passing the `-Command` argument to your `powershell` call.

Comment: @BryceMcDonald Most environments shut down WinRM for whatever security reasons even if it's far more secure than RPC.

Comment: @BryceMcDonald - I added below line in my code just above the Invoke-Expression line:.\psexec.exe \\$server powershell Enable-PSRemoting -Force. Now it includes this - "WinRM already is set up to receive requests on this machine" in the output , rest all same. Error not resolved. In case I misunderstood  your reply, you can please kindly provide the required lines of code.

Comment: @BriteRoy that would be the correct code to enable WinRM and PSRemoting.  Are you able to use Invoke-Command now?  If not, you may be in an environment that does not allow PSRemoting (even though it sounds like they and I both don't agree with the usual justifications for it), in which case I'd defer to @TheIncorrigible1 and his answer of using `&`

Comment: @BryceMcDonald - No Invoke-Command still throws WinRM error. I'm trying few other things from google, but all going in vain. Can you please elaborate the '&' method by TheIncorrigible1 ?

Comment: @BriteRoy the `&` is a call operator used to call scripts, functions, and other commands.  You can [click this link for more info](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)

Comment: I tried but couldn't find how to use '&' for remote computers. I'm baffled right now after trying all this,because psexec is able to connect separately to remote server but not able to execute powershell commands. There is something really minor I'm missing :( not sure how to get over it. @BryceMcDonald - Please suggest !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried running psexec in interactive mode by using `-i`?  I'm actually pretty bugged that you can get he hostname but nothing else will work.

Comment: Good news is: today I tried again and able to now run powershell commands but with some restriction:
$a=".\psexec.exe \\$server powershell Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework"
Invoke-Expression "$($a)"
This gives me all files and folders inside windir/Microsoft of remote servers.

Comment: BAD news is: First, I can not run filters inside the powershell query , for eg below command doesnt executes (although runs separately): $a=".\psexec.exe \\$server powershell (Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name" .  Error is: - "The term 'v4.0.30319' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function". This means that script is able to run the first part but fails to read the filtered clauses to sort it and fetch the 'FIRST' value. Any idea how to make the entire line read it as a whole as a command?